# How do I plot 2 variables on the same map with a single palette with Cartopy?

Tags: python, netcdf, cartopy

I'm stuck here.
My code:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np

from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fname = os.path.join("path", "file")
dataset = netcdf_dataset(fname)

lats = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
lons = dataset.variables['lon'][:]
IVT = dataset.variables['IVT'][0,:,:]
IVTm = dataset.variables['IVTm'][0,:,:]


ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

map_ivt=ax.contourf(lons, lats, IVT, 60,
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
map_ivt=ax.contourf(lons, lats, IVTm, 60,
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.colorbar(map_ivt, orientation='horizontal')

ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()

plt.show()
```

This is my result (I think that my palette is not showing the right value, both the variables have values over 800):

[image]

Can't find the proper way to plot 'IVT' and 'IVTm' on the same map as in the example under here (IVT in red, IVTm in blue):

[image: IVT is in red, IVTm is in blue]

I would need to plot the two quantities with a palette that goes in both way as in the example.

Thank you.

Comment: Use options `zorder=10, alpha=0.6` for second  `ax.contourf()`. The first filled-contour below will be seen.

Comment: not sure I understand those options. Seems that they just fade contours and grids but my palette's values remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have this work with two separate calls to `contourf`, you'd have to make a custom colormap that has alpha of 0 for certain values, which seems like a lot of work. The easy way here, if the values really don't overlap, is to combine them together into a single array and plot that with `contourf`:

```
IVT_combined = np.where(IVT > 0, IVT, IVTm)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna try this